# AudioPlayer is Possibly null causing vercel to fail to compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Here is the current code

import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { FaPlay, FaPause, FaForward, FaBackward } from "react-icons/fa";

```
export default function Player() {
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
const [currentSongIndex, setCurrentSongIndex] = useState(0);
const audioRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>(null);
const songs = [
    { src: "/audio/fairtrade.mp3", title: "Fair Trade", },
    { src: "/audio/donotdisturb.mp3", title: "Do Not Disturb", },
    { src: "/audio/jimmycooks.mp3", title: "Jimmy Cooks", },];

useEffect(() => {
    const audioPlayer = audioRef.current;

    if (audioPlayer && isPlaying) {
        audioPlayer.currentTime = currentTime;
        audioPlayer.play();
    } else if (audioPlayer) {
        audioPlayer.pause();
    }

    // Add event listener for ended event
    const handleNext = () => {
        const nextSongIndex = currentSongIndex === songs.length - 1 ? 0 : currentSongIndex +     1;
        setCurrentSongIndex(nextSongIndex);
        setIsPlaying(false);
        setCurrentTime(0);
    };

    audioPlayer.addEventListener("ended", handleNext);

    // Cleanup function to remove event listener
    return () => {
        audioPlayer.removeEventListener("ended", handleNext);
    };
}, [currentSongIndex, isPlaying]);


useEffect(() => {
    const audioPlayer = audioRef.current;
    if (audioPlayer) {
        audioPlayer.src = songs[currentSongIndex].src;
        audioPlayer.load();
    }
}, [currentSongIndex]);


const togglePlay = () => {
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
};

const handleTimeUpdate = () => {
    const audioPlayer = audioRef.current;
    if (audioPlayer) {
        setCurrentTime(audioPlayer.currentTime);
        setDuration(audioPlayer.duration);
    }
};

const handleNext = () => {
    const nextSongIndex = currentSongIndex === songs.length - 1 ? 0 : currentSongIndex + 1;
    setCurrentSongIndex(nextSongIndex);
    setIsPlaying(false);
    setCurrentTime(0);
};

const handlePrevious = () => {
    const previousSongIndex = currentSongIndex === 0 ? songs.length - 1 : currentSongIndex - 1;
    setCurrentSongIndex(previousSongIndex);
    setIsPlaying(false);
    setCurrentTime(0);
};

const handleSeekBarChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const audioPlayer = audioRef.current;
    if (audioPlayer) {
        audioPlayer.currentTime = Number(event.target.value);
        setCurrentTime(audioPlayer.currentTime);
    }
};``
```

[Error from Vercel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxNQM.png)

What do i do to change this. Been trying but i cant seem to understand where my error is.

Lines 33 & 37 are the ones in error

I tried to add a check before accessing the audioPlayer object in lines 33 & 37 but then it doesnt work.

**EDIT**

So sorry for my noob question, all i had to do was `audioPlayer?.addEventListener("ended", handleNext);` by placing a ?

Answer (score 0):

Added `?` to both lines 33 and 37 to make it `audioPlayer?.addEventListener("ended", handleNext);`

```
audioPlayer?.removeEventListener("ended", handleNext);
```

fixed the error entirely.